# Why is no warning given for the wrong use of __attribute__((pure)) in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, function-attributes

I am trying to understand pure functions, and have been reading through the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) on that topic. I wrote the minimal sample program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a = 1;

static __attribute__((pure)) int pure_function(int x, int y)
{
        return x + y;
}

static __attribute__((pure)) int impure_function(int x, int y)
{
        a++;
        return x + y;
}

int main(void)
{
        printf("pure_function(0, 0) = %d\n", pure_function(0, 0));
        printf("impure_function(0, 0) = %d\n", impure_function(0, 0));

        return 0;
}
```

I compiled this program with `gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra`, expecting that an error, or at least a warning, should have been issued for decorating `impure_function()` with `__attribute__((pure))`. However, I received no warnings or errors, and the program also ran without issues.

Isn't marking `impure_function()` with `__attribute__((pure))` incorrect? If so, why does it compile without any errors or warnings, even with the `-Wextra` and `-Wall` flags?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are telling the compiler that other functions should optimize as if impure_function was pure. That can make sense even if the function is *not* pure, because for instance you don't care about the side effects.

Comment: This attribute is not for the *compiler* to check, it is something that you are as a programmer tell the compiler assuming it can't infer it by itself. So you are basically lying to it and will be lucky if the compiler is not optimizing it based on this lie.

Comment: Probably because they didn't think it is worth the time spent implementing such warning. You try to implement one yourself since GCC is open source.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I understand your comment correctly, the compiler ignores the attribute, and doesn't optimise `impure_function()`?

Comment: @AbhishekChakravarti The documentation of this attribute does not state the behavior of this case, so I can't tell for sure if it is taken as "suggestion" only or it will rely on this to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure function is a hint for the [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). Probably, `gcc`  don't care about pure functions when you pass just `-O0` to it (the default optimizations). So if `f` is pure (and defined *outside* of your [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), e.g. in some outside library), the GCC compiler *might* optimize `y = f(x) + f(x);` into something like

```
{ 
  int tmp = f(x); /// tmp is a fresh variable, not appearing elsewhere
  y = tmp + tmp;
}
```

but if `f` is *not* pure (which is the usual case: think of `f` calling `printf` or `malloc`), such an optimization is forbidden.

Standard math functions like [`sin`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sin.3.html) or [`sqrt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html) are pure (except for IEEE rounding mode craziness, see http://floating-point-gui.de/ and [Fluctuat](https://indico.mathrice.fr/event/166/contribution/11/material/slides/0.pdf) for more), and they are complex enough to compute to make such optimizations worthwhile.

You might compile your code with `gcc -O2 -Wall -fdump-tree-all` to guess what is happening inside the compiler. You could add the `-fverbose-asm -S` flags to get a generated `*.s` assembler file.

You could also read the [Bismon draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) (notably its section §1.4). It might give some intuitions related to your question.

In your particular case, I am guessing that `gcc` is [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) your calls; and then purity matters less.

If you have time to spend, you might consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to make such a warning. You'll spend months in writing it! [These old](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/gcc-plugin-MELT-LinuxCollabSummit2014.pdf) slides might still be useful to you, even if the details are obsolete.

At the theoretical level, be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). A consequence of it is that perfect optimization of pure functions is probably impossible.

Be aware of the [GCC Resource Center](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/), located in Bombay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the references provided.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this is incorrect and you are responsible for using the attribute correctly.

Look at this example:

```
static __attribute__((pure)) int impure_function(int x, int y)
{
        extern int a;
        a++;
        return x + y;
}

void caller()
{
    impure_function(1, 1);
}
```

Code generated by GCC (with `-O1`) for the function `caller` is:

```
caller():
        ret
```

As you can see, the `impure_function` call was completely removed because compiler treats it as "pure".

GCC can mark the function as "pure" internally automatically if it sees its definition:

```
static __attribute__((noinline)) int pure_function(int x, int y)
{
        return x + y;
}

void caller()
{
    pure_function(1, 1);
}
```

Generated code:

```
caller():
        ret
```

So there is no point in using this attribute on functions that are visible to the compiler. It is supposed to be used when definition is not available, for example when function is defined in another DLL. That means that when it is used in a proper place the compiler won't be able to perform a sanity check anyway. Implementing a warning thus is not very useful (although not meaningless).

I don't think there is anything stopping GCC developers from implementing such warning, except time that must be spend.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I liked it and have upvoted it. However, I have accepted the answer provided by Basile Starynkevitch owing to the references provided. Thanks again!